# Unicode/Japanese characters in a Java applet

Tags: java, unicode, applet

I'm writing an applet that's supposed to show both English and Japanese (unicode) characters on a JLabel. The Japanese characters show up fine when I run the applet on my system, but all I get is mojibake when I run it from the web page. The page can display Japanese characters if they're hard-coded into the HTML, but not in the applet. I'm pretty sure I've seen this sort of thing working before. Is there anything I can do in the Java code to fix this?

Comment: Where is the text coming from? Where is the applet reading the text that it then displays? Is it a param? Is it the result of a request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I'm not sure what was causing the problem, but I set EVERYTHING to read in and display out in UTF-8 and it seems to work now.

Answer (score 1):

My first guess would be that the servlet container is not sending back the right character set for your webapp resources.  Have a look at the response in an HTTP sniffer to see what character set is included - if the response says that the charset is e.g. CP-1252, then Japanese characters would not be decoded correctly.

You *may* be able to fix this in code by explicitly setting a Content-Type header with the right charset; but I'd argue it's more appropriate to fix the servlet container's config to return the correct character set for the relevant resources.